# get sibling controls

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Is there some way to find sibling controls / or sibling activity?

In ASP.NET I found a solution by user md1337 [solution's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685530/finding-the-previous-and-next-sibling-controls), but for WF4 I can't find it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In what context?  Design time or run time?  And why are you trying to do this?  There might be an easier way...

Comment: In Design time... For example when I drag an activity into the designer, I would like to know the content's of the previous activity textbox to use this value in this dragged activity.

Comment: ... My idea is to get the previous activity information, for example what kind of activity is, what controls it has...

Comment: Yeah, you're doing it wrong.  You should be binding in/out arguments to get that kind of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(System.Windows.DependencyObject depObj) where T : System.Windows.DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                System.Windows.DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And in mi Create Activity method I do:

```
 foreach (TextBlock tb in RulesDll.ObjectsClass.FindControls.FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(target))
        {
            string a = tb.Text;
        }
```