# Get value of label in C# CodeBehind, when label does not have an id attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, label, code-behind

I have a `<label>` that does not have an `id` attribute. It only has a `for` attribute. Can I get the value of this label in CodeBehind C#?

This application is built in ASP.NET.

```
<label for="txtEmpCd">Department</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `<asp:Label>` instead of `<label>`?

Comment: I agree, using the ASP control would work best - otherwise the Codebehind won't recognize the label as an object without the runat="server", just sees it as HTML text.

Comment: No but we can make this change, But to create id its very difficult because our application is too big

Comment: Without id, ASP label would work??

Comment: I've never heard of an application being too big to use HTML ids.

Comment: So what is your recommendation, we must require ids?

Comment: If it is not `runat="server"` and not having some id it can't be accessed in code behind.

Comment: We can add runat="server" by using find and replace.
IDs also necessary??

Comment: Been a while since I did aspx but have you tried looping through the controls for the parent of the dropdownlist - see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685530/finding-the-previous-and-next-sibling-controls, not sure if the label is available if it is not runat server, but I think it should be

Comment: Cool @Pete Let me check if it can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can access a `<asp:Label>` without an ID, but it will require recursively searching through the controls on the page. This will require the label to be in the form:

`<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="txtEmpCd" runat="server" />`

You will need to define a recursive function as such:

```
private void LoopThroughLabels(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        Label label = c as Label;
        if (label != null)
        {
            if (label.AssociatedControlID == "txtEmpCd")
            {
                // This is your label
            }
        }

        if (c.HasControls())
        {
            LoopThroughLabels(c);
        }
    }
}
```

And for the first call, pass in the `Page`:

```
LoopThroughLabels(Page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Label` with an `AssociatedControlID`

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Department" AssociatedControlID="DropDownList4"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: If I use Client ID inline, How will I get the Label Value in CodeBehind C#?? Can you please add that also??

Comment: The second suggestion doesn't really answer the question either, although with `<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"...`, you can then use `Label1` to access the label and get the value.

Comment: @Lalji You cannot do anything without an ID.

Comment: Okay Thanks Just wanted to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access from codebehind without having runat="server".

If you only can access from codebehind, find read all html literals in entire page, get element having for attribute is "txtEmpCd" which is very tedious and not the right way to do so.

In jQuery (client side), you can find label which has for attribute is "txtEmpCd" also tedious as well.

My suggestion! Why don't you add ID="txtEmpCd" to your label?